# Не могу получить ид автора слэш-команды. Discord net

Tags: c#, discord

Когда я получаю автора слэш-команды с помощью SocketMessageComponent он почему то всегда равен тому кто взаимодействует со компонентом interaction Context.Interaction.User.Id.
Мне нужно получить ид того кто автор вызова слэш-команды и кто нажимает на компонент слэш-команды.
Вот код обработки компонента который находится в классе команды /play:

```cs
        [ComponentInteraction("cancelBtn")]
        public async Task cancelBtn()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Context.Interaction is SocketMessageComponent zxc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(zxc.User.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(Context.Interaction.User.Id);
                    if (zxc.User != Context.Interaction.User) { await RespondAsync($"⛔️ Для взаимодействия с кнопками вы должны быть автором сообщения(/play)! ", ephemeral: true);  return; }
                    var msg = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(zxc.Message.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.Content);
                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        await msg.DeleteAsync();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await FollowupAsync($"⛔️ Не удалось найти сообщение.", ephemeral: true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Помогите пожалуйста как все-таки узнать автора вызова слэш-команды.

Comment: Я вам сказал уже в предыдущем [вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527542/i-cant-get-the-author-of-the-slash-command-discord-net-c#comment2745189_1527542) что надо делать и как, вместо того, чтоб его отредактировать, вы создали полную копию, еще и проигнорировав мое сообщение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я уже убрал эфемерное сообщение просто сделав UpdateAsync и теперь сообщение удаляется, но не могу получить автора вызова слэш-команды.

Comment: Зачем убирать эфемерное сообщение я не пойму? Я вам наоборот говорю, чтоб вы использовали эфемерное сообщение, и убрали эту проверку на "авторство", она лишняя, ибо только тот кто вызвал может увидеть его. Ну и да, я не вижу, чтоб вы использовали `wild card`, как это показано в документации....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я уже принципиально не хочу использовать ephemeral. Т.к это создаёт некоторые проблемы.

Comment: Проблемы не должны влиять на конфиденциальность и безопасность, проблемы надо решать, а не бросать. Я конечно не знаю, что вы там делаете, но как пример, если человеку дается условно "пароль", или например его игровые данные (баланс, счет, предметы, и пр.), то согласитесь, не очень светить этим на публику, и не каждому понравиться такая открытость. В любом случае, все нужное я вам уже дал, дальше подстраивайте под свою задачу.